# Definite integration with e: $\int_0^1 (\mathrm{e}x-x\mathrm{e}^x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So I was practising definite integration when I came across this one.

$$\int_0^1 (\mathrm{e}x-x\mathrm{e}^x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

So I calculated this to be:

$$\int_0^1 \mathrm{e}x\,\mathrm{d}x - \int_0^1 x\mathrm{e}^x\,\mathrm{d}x = (\mathrm{e}\cdot1^2/2-0)-(1^2/2\cdot \mathrm{e}^1-0)=\mathrm{e}/2-\mathrm{e}/2$$
The answer should be:

$$1/2\mathrm{e}-\mathrm{e}+\mathrm{e}-1=1/2\mathrm{e}-1$$

So what do I miss here? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: $x^2/2\cdot e^x$ is not an anti-derivative of $xe^x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first term is easy to integrate and for the second one integrate two times by parts. A possible answer for the indefinite integral is given by $$\frac{ex^2}{2}-xe^x+e^x+C$$